# Question about von Neumann algebra generated by a complete algebra of projections

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Hi all, sorry if this is a dumb question, I don't know much about von Neumann algebras except the definition and a few relevant facts I've managed to prove by myself so I expect the answer will turn out to be well known. Anyway, let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and suppose that $P$ is a commuting set of self-adjoint projections on $\mathcal{H}$, with the additional two properties:

1) $P$ is closed under complements, i.e. if $p \in P$ then so is $1 - p$.

2) $P$ is closed under suprema of arbitrary subsets, i.e. if $S \subseteq P$ then $\sup S \in P$ (here the projections on $\mathcal{H}$ are ordered by defining $p \leq q$ whenever the range of $p$ is contained in the range of $q$).

Now let $V$ denote the smallest von Neumann algebra containing $P$. Suppose that $p \in V$ is a self-adjoint projection. Is $p \in P$?

I know that $p$ is necessarily in the closure (relative to the weak operator topology) of the set of finite sums $\sum_i \lambda_i p_i$, where $p_i \in P$ and $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$. It seems like it may be possible to derive a contradiction from the assumption that $q$ has a strictly smaller range than $p$, where $q \equiv \sup ${$ r \in P | r \leq p $}. But I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer "yes" follows from Theorem 2.8 of Bade's "[On Boolean algebras of projections and algebras of operators](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-02/S0002-9947-1955-0073954-0/home.html)," 1955, which is in the more general context of algebras of operators on a Banach space.

Bade had previously proven a less general result that still covers your case, dealing with algebras of operators on reflexive spaces, in Theorem 3.4 of "[Weak and strong limits of spectral operators](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103044796)," 1954.

Comment: That's great, thanks. It will take me a while to digest the papers but it's good to know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is off the cuff, not a complete answer, and I haven't checked through it carefully, but it was getting too long for a comment. I'm making it community wiki in case someone sees a way to iron out the wrinkles, although if they have a better approach they should feel free to write it up as a separate answer.

Anyway. Since $V$ is an abelian von Neumann algebra, it has the form $C(\Omega)$ for some compact, [extremally disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) toppological space. Then your original set $P$ can be regarded as the set of indicator functions of a family $\mathcal F$ of clopen subsets; $\mathcal F$ is closed under taking complements and under formation of arbitrary unions.

Here is the part which I haven't quite nailed down at time of writing: we note/claim that any element of $V$ is the pointwise limit of some bounded net of finite linear combinations of characteristic functions of sets in ${\mathcal F}$, in particular $p$, which must be the indicator function of some clopen $X\subseteq\Omega$, must be approximable in this way. Now we consider the family ${\mathcal C}$ of all $A\in{\mathcal F}$ which  have non-empty intersection with $X$. The approximability assumption should force $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal C} A$ to be $X$, and thus $X\in\mathcal F$, which is the same as saying that $p\in P$ as required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though there are a couple of points I don't get. Am I right in thinking that $\Omega$ can be taken to be the maximal ideal space of $V$? If so then can't we only assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under closures of arbitrary unions, rather than the unions themselves? If so I don't think this really matters, see below.

I don't think your choice of $\mathcal{C}$ works - if $X$ is non-empty then surely the whole of $\Omega$ is in $\mathcal{C}$? Suppose instead we let $\mathcal{C}$ consist of all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $A \subseteq X$. [contd.]

Comment: Then if $B \equiv \overline{\cup \mathcal{C}}$ then clearly $B \subseteq X$. To show the reverse inclusion, let $x \in X$ . By your statement about pointwise limits, for each $y$ not in $X$ there exists $A \in \mathcal{F}$  such that $x \in A$ , and some neighbourhood of $y$ is disjoint from $A$. By compactness, a finite set of such neighbourhoods covers the complement of $X$ ; the intersection of the corresponding $A$'s is in $\mathcal{F}$, contains $x$ and is contained in $X$, so $x \in B$. [contd.]

Comment: This leaves your claim that every element of $V$ is the pointwise limit of a net of etc. I don't see why this is so, is it possible to explain to a know-nothing like me? I haven't been able to figure out any "nice" description of the topology on $C(\Omega)$ which makes the natural isomorphism $C(\Omega) \to V$ into a homeomorphism.

By the way, can anybody reading this recommend a good introductory text book where I can read about Von Neumann algebras? I've read Rudin's "Functional Analysis" and that's pretty much the limit of my knowledge.

Comment: typo $\mathcal V=\mathcal F$ (fixed)

Comment: Phil: sorry for the incomplete nature of my "answer" - I'm afraid I have v. limited internet access for the next few days so probably won't be able to respond properly until then. But I'll try to think a bit more about how this can be patched up.